# How to prevent from DNS spoofing in Java code which obtains a name of localhost

Tags: java, dns-spoofing

FORTIFY static scan has detected that this piece of our java code is vulnerable to DNS spoofing attack:

```
public String getLocalhostName(){
    try {
        return Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

FORTIFY also gives these recommendations:

> **Recommendations:**

> You can increase confidence in a domain name lookup if you check to
> make sure that the host's forward and backward DNS entries match.
> Attackers will not be able to spoof both the forward and the reverse
> DNS entries without controlling the nameservers for the target domain.
> This is not a foolproof approach however: attackers may be able to
> convince the domain registrar to turn over the domain to a malicious
> nameserver. Basing authentication on DNS entries is simply a risky
> proposition.

---

The host name retrieved by this code is later saved in logs and in the database - only for audit purposes (we want to know which record in the table comes from which server). So in our specific case I think there is no any risk. But I'am courious to know an example of the scenario that is voulnerable to such an attack, because I can;t imagine any.

---

**My questions are:**

1. Is getting the local host name really vulnerable to such an attack ? I can't imagine such a scenario.
2. How to implement this check in practice (in this code snippet)?

Tkank you.

Comment: What is the context? What do you use this information for? Most hosts will not have a meaningful reverse DNS entry anyway. And local interfaces will likely have a RFC1918-address, which will not be in DNS...

Comment: @vidarlo The host name retrieved by this code is later saved in logs and in the database - only for audit purposes (we want to know which record in the table comes from which server). So in our specific case I think there is no any risk. But I'am courious to know  an example of the scenario that is voulnerable to such an attack, because I can;t imagine any.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question to be more general, and less specific then.

Answer (score 2):

While static code analysis can improve security, it is wise to take the **context** into consideration. Same thing is done with vulnerability analysis reports.

In your code as written, there is no sensitive details being sent to the server (localhost in this case). So there is something else throwing the issue, and you may want to detail that.

What the analysis report is likely *trying* to tell you is:

> verify the server through some other means before sending credentials.

This can be done with certificate pinning, which embeds a certificate chain or thumbprint into the program. Java has a built-in "keystore" functionality for this purpose.

There are libraries in many different languages that do DNS ([like this one for Java](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava)), but suggesting a check on "both the forward and the reverse DNS entries" seems awkward and futile.

Again context matters as with DNS and certificate pinning, there are ways around it.

If you start with "What's the actual risk to the program I'm writing?", better answers can come about.

Comment: Sample code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47680204/1756069